# Calling a function from a child class

Tags: php

I have a feeling that what I am trying to do is impossible as I can't find anything on it. I have a few classes that extend from another class. Inside of the class that is being extended, I have to call some unique code based on which class is calling it.

This is something of an in-depth project, so I created a testcase that should explain what I am trying to do:

```
class parent {
    function traverseTable($table) {
        foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') {
            $rowCnt++;
            $this->uniqueSearch($rowCnt);
        }
    }
}

class child1 extends parent {
    function search($input) {
        //parse input, get $table
        $this->traverseTable($table);
    }

    function uniqueSearch($rowCnt) {
         echo 'child1';
        //Do different things
    }
}

class child2 extends parent {
    function search($input) {
        //parse input, get $table
        $this->traverseTable($table);
    }

    function uniqueSearch($rowCnt) {
         echo 'child2';
        //Do different things
    }
}
```

Basically, I want to be able to call the uniqueSearch() function from inside the loop in Class Parent; but the above syntax does not seem to work. Anybody have any ideas? The real size of the uniqueSearch functions vary from 20-100 lines at this point, but might get bigger.

Comment: Why is there a blank line between each line of actual code?

Comment: Could you define "seems not to work"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you want to call `uniqueSearch` polymorphically.

1. [Your first problem](http://codepad.org/7eagIrUe) has nothing to do with this, and is that `parent` is a reserved word:

   > Fatal error: Cannot use 'parent' as class name as it is reserved on line 2

   Fix that.
2. [Your next problem](http://codepad.org/QhrikNgY) is a simple syntax error:

   > Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' on line 4

   Fix that.
3. Then, [you have the issue](http://codepad.org/Gi0wJCmo) that there is no `$table`, and no `getElementsByTagName` in your testcase. Also `foreach ($table->getElementsByTagName('tr'))` is not valid PHP.

   Fix that.
4. [Your testcase doesn't call any functions](http://codepad.org/21PYsB3H).

   Fix that.

Result:

```
<?php
class base {
    function traverseTable($table) {
        foreach ($table as $element) {
            $rowCnt++;
            $this->uniqueSearch($rowCnt);
        }
    }
}

class child1 extends base {
    function search($input) {
        //parse input, get $table
        // dummy for now:
        $table = Array(0,1,2,3);
        $this->traverseTable($table);
    }

    function uniqueSearch($rowCnt) {
         echo 'child1';
        //Do different things
    }
}

class child2 extends base {
    function search($input) {
        //parse input, get $table
        // dummy for now:
        $table = Array(0,1,2,3);
        $this->traverseTable($table);
    }

    function uniqueSearch($rowCnt) {
         echo 'child2';
        //Do different things
    }
}

$c1 = new child1;
$c2 = new child2;

$c1->search("");
$c2->search("");
?>
```

And [now it works just fine](http://codepad.org/DuBZfPhL):

> child1child1child1child1child2child2child2child2

This question had nothing to do with polymorphism whatsoever, as it turns out; just silly syntax errors.

Thanks for playing.

Answer (score 1):

Declare `uniqueSearch()` inside parent class as abstract method (that implies that class also has to be declared as abstract). That means each child must implement `uniqueSearch()` method itself, so it definitely is there.

```
abstract class parent {
    function traverseTable($table) {
        foreach($table->getElementsByTagName('tr') {
            $rowCnt++;
            $this->uniqueSearch($rowCnt);
        }
    }

    abstract function uniqueSearch($rowCnt);
}
```